# TSQL Nested CASE with Condition

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, nested, case, distinct-values

I am attempting to write a CASE statement that will give me a distinct Value for Each asset. The below code executes with no error but if an asset Passes and Fails each result is written. I only need a distinct result per asset and it is based on the CASE statement.

Below is an example result from the query in it's current form

```
ServerID    IP  HOSTNAME    CARS_SubBusiness    STATUS  Technology  FailureReason
20979   1.1.1.1 myhost1      Business1          PASSED   Windows       -
20979   1.1.1.1 myhost1      Business1          FAILED   UNIX         Unable to complete Unix login
```

In this instance I only need to return the PASSED result.

```
Exclusion + * = Exclusion
Pass + * = Pass
FAIL + Not Attempted/No Results = FAIL
Not Attempted = Not Attempted
No Results = No Results
```

If it passes and fails I only need the passing information, if it is excluded but has any other status I only need Exclusion as the status and so on..

```
SELECT  auth.ServerID, auth.IP, auth.HOSTNAME, auth.CARS_SubBusiness, 

    CASE MAX (CASE
                (CASE
                    (CASE WHEN [Status] LIKE 'PASSED' AND ExclusionType IS NOT NULL 
                        THEN 6 WHEN [Status] LIKE 'FAILED' AND ExclusionType IS NOT NULL THEN 6 WHEN [STATUS] LIKE 'Not Attempted' AND ExclusionType IS NOT NULL 
                        THEN 6 WHEN [Status] LIKE 'PASSED' AND ExclusionType IS NULL THEN 5 WHEN [Status] LIKE 'FAILED' AND ExclusionType IS NULL 
                        THEN 4 WHEN [STATUS] LIKE 'Not Attempted' AND ExclusionType IS NULL THEN 3 ELSE 0 END) 
                 WHEN 6 THEN 'Excluded' WHEN 5 THEN 'PASSED' WHEN 4 THEN 'FAILED' WHEN 3 THEN 'Not Attempted' ELSE 'No Results' END) 
            WHEN 'Excluded' THEN 5
            WHEN 'Not Attempted' THEN 4
            WHEN 'No Results' THEN 3
            WHEN 'PASSED' then 2
            WHEN 'FAILED' then 1 END) 
                      WHEN 5 THEN 'EXCLUDED' 
                      WHEN 4 THEN 'Not Attempted'
                      WHEN 3 THEN 'No Results'
                      WHEN 2 THEN 'PASSED'
                      WHEN 1 THEN 'FAILED'
                      END AS [STATUS], auth.Technology, 
                      auth.FailureReason
    FROM     _CombinedAuthentication AS auth RIGHT OUTER JOIN
                      BusinessTranslations AS bt ON auth.BusinessID = bt.BusinessID
    WHERE  (auth.ActiveFlag IS NOT NULL)
    GROUP BY auth.ServerID, auth.IP,auth.CARS_SubBusiness,  auth.HOSTNAME, auth.Technology, auth.FailureReason
```

Comment: And your problem is...?

Comment: @JayC I only need a distinct result per asset and it is based on the CASE statement.

Exclusion + * = Exclusion
Pass + * = Pass
FAIL + Not Attempted/No Results = FAIL
Not Attempted = Not Attempted
No Results = No Results

Comment: "I only need a distinct result per asset" - okay, so if there are *multiple* possible results, what rules are we (and SQL Server, eventually) meant to use to pick one result? These rules must be based on data that we have available (e.g. the result with the largest `sproog` value, where `sproog` is a column in one of your tables)

Comment: Let me check-  are you trying to have a different set of columns for the different scenarios?  That is tough in one query.  Or can you have some of the columns remain as NULL, or say "n/a", when they aren't needed?  Can you post an example result set that shows where you're going?

Comment: I have posted a sample output. Not all of the duplicates are pass/fail.  I suppose what I need is a CASE statement that will only give me the entire record for a matching CASE.

Comment: That example is very helpful.  In fact, the reason CASE isn't helping, then, is because it doesn't help you skip rows.  CASE can only create a computed or modified value for a row, not skip it.  We need a solution using WHERE or JOIN :) !  I'll try to come back to this when I have time to make a code suggestion in an answer.

Comment: ... or how about Min() / Max() with GROUP BY on that integer hierarchy of cases...

Answer (score 0):

you may want to consider using sets, something like this:

```
select auth.ServerID, auth.IP,auth.CARS_SubBusiness,  auth.HOSTNAME, auth.Technology, auth.FailureReason,status
from bla where status='exclusion'
union
select auth.ServerID, auth.IP,auth.CARS_SubBusiness,  auth.HOSTNAME, auth.Technology, auth.FailureReason,status
from bla where status='pass' and not exists (select 1 from bla where status='exclusion' and...)
union
select auth.ServerID, auth.IP,auth.CARS_SubBusiness,  auth.HOSTNAME, auth.Technology, auth.FailureReason,status
from bla where status='fail' and not exists (select 1 from bla where status='exclusion' and ...) 
                             and not exists (select 1 from bla where status='pass' and ...) 
union
select auth.ServerID, auth.IP,auth.CARS_SubBusiness,  auth.HOSTNAME, auth.Technology, auth.FailureReason,status
from bla where status='Not Attempted' and not exists (select 1 from bla where status='exclusion' and ...) 
                                      and not exists (select 1 from bla where status='pass' and ...) 
                                      and not exists (select 1 from bla where status='fail' and ..) 
union
select auth.ServerID, auth.IP,auth.CARS_SubBusiness,  auth.HOSTNAME, auth.Technology, auth.FailureReason,status
from bla where status='No Result' and not exists (select 1 from bla where status='exclusion' and ...) 
                                  and not exists (select 1 from bla where status='pass' and ...) 
                                  and not exists (select 1 from bla where status='fail' and ..) 
                                  and not exists (select 1 from bla where status='Not Attempted' and ..)
```

this solution can probably be improved using CTE as well